# LINQ-to-SQL Query Timing Out

Tags: linq-to-sql

I'm running this query in LINQ:

```
var unalloc = db.slot_sp_getUnallocatedJobs("Repair", 
                  RadComboBox1.SelectedValue, 20);
```

It runs when I first open the page, but when I go back to it and try to run the same query with a different value, "Con", being passed through, the `linq to sql designer.cs` tells me that I've got a timeout error.

Any ideas?

**Edit:** This is what's in the designer:

```
[Function(Name="dbo.slot_sp_getUnallocatedJobs")]
Public ISingleResult<slot_sp_getUnallocatedJobsResult> slot_sp_getUnallocatedJobs([Parameter(Name="JobType", DbType="VarChar(20)")] string jobType, [Parameter(Name="Contract", DbType="VarChar(10)")] string contract, [Parameter(Name="Num", DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> num)
        {
            IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), jobType, contract, num);
            return ((ISingleResult<slot_sp_getUnallocatedJobsResult>)(result.ReturnValue));
        }
    }
```

This is the error:

```
SQLException was unhandled by user code
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

Comment: it looks like the stored procedure "slot_sp_getUnallocatedJobs" is taking a long time to complete. what is the sql code in there, tables used, and indexes on them.  how many rows in the tables. does this happen every time for the one parameter value, are other user on the system making changes to the data when this runs

Comment: it happens every time for the one parameter value and not there isnt any other users making changed to the data when i run the query

Comment: Can you connect to the database and run the SP manually with those same parameters?  If so, does it take a long time to run it?

Comment: what is the sql code in there, tables used, and indexes on them. how many rows in the tables

Comment: lunchy no it doesnt take long at all to run the query in the database manually it just takes time when im running it through c# and linq

Comment: Ok, so you know it's not an issue with the database itself. I've seen this behavior before but can't remember what the issue was. Are you sure the perms your app is using has the proper perms to run that proc or to access the tables/views etc that it's using?